# Nemo is not generating thumbnails

Tags: nemo

I am using Nemo on Unity. Nemo is not generating thumbnails in 12.04 but Nautilus does it so well. Why can't Nemo do itself independently?

Comment: Have enabled thumbnails in Nemo?

Comment: Where I can enable it in Nemo? In settings I selected smaller than 4GB.

Comment: Also have you selected generation for all files

Comment: There is not any option for it.

Comment: Oh, I dont know that. have followed this http://www.webupd8.org/2013/10/install-nemo-with-unity-patches-and.html

Comment: Already answered in detail [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/395911/why-doesnt-nemo-preview-thumbnails). In my case, I solved it by **increasing** the the maximum size of previewable files to 1 GB (see *Preferences > Display*)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case there's still anyone using **nemo** on Ubuntu 12.04 (or Linux Mint 13) I've encountered the same issue.

The problem is explained [here](http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=47&t=152256#p800264) and seems to be a bug in this particular version of nemo.

As a temporary solution, you can remove the ~/.thumbnails directory and replace it with a symlink to ~/.cache/thumbnails

To do this, run the following 2 commands in the terminal:

```
rm -r ~/.thumbnails
ln -s ~/.cache/thumbnails ~/.thumbnails
```

Some in the linked post above have reported side effects like compounding thumbnails in the ~/.cache/thumbnails directory due to the symlink, but I haven't had any issue.  My guess is they were switching between using both nemo and nautilus which wrote to both directories.