# Why doesn't Nemo preview thumbnails?

Tags: cinnamon, thumbnails, nemo

I have a problem with thumbnails on my Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 32-bit system with Cinnamon 2.0.14 DE and Nemo 2.08.

I have tried removing the `~/.thumbnails` directory but it is not working for me. This is very weird because when I open an image in *Eye of GNOME*, Nemo is creating thumbnails but other images doesn't have preview thumbnails as one can see in my screenshots below. I have changed the preview settings as *show miniatures always*.

Screenshot 1:

[image: directory full of images]

Screenshot 2:

[image: settings]

Answer (score 45):

Nemo makes previews only for files less than one MB by default. You can change this from its preferences:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: This worked for me in Nemo-2.4.4

Comment: I know this is an old question, but do you know how to set the size as a  custom value? I'm looking for thumbs on files smaller than 25MB, any ideas?

Comment: 8 years later, working with nemo 4.4.2, and I had the same problem with the same solution :´) Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

The solution below works for 32 and 64 bit systems (tested on cinnamon 17):

In your home directory remove the `.thumbnails` subdirectory:

```
rm ~/.thumbnails
```

Set a new link for the cache folder:

```
cd ~
ln -s .cache/thumbnails .thumbnails
```

Answer (score 2):

The solution for my in Xubuntu 18.04 x386 is to delete these folders by putting in a terminal:

```
rm -fr ~/.thumbnails
rm -fr ~/.cache/thumbnails
```

then open Nemo and he will say a message that there is a problem with the cache of the icons:

[image: repair cache]

now he asks me to put my password

[image: set password]

And see, working fine:

[image: here]

Answer (score 1):

To fully flush everything out consistantly, I ended up having to use a small script to clear out all the cached files and reset the symbolic link to the cache folder. This worked for both nemo and nautalus. I made sure to shut down the file manager at the end of the script too. Then when I next opened the folder, all the thumbnails reloaded. Be sure the file size for thumbnails is set high enough. I have a couple MP3 files over 10meg so I have my preview level set to 100meg.

```
#!/bin/bash

find ~/.cache/thumbnails/ -type f -exec rm {} \;
rm -rf ~/.thumbnails
ln -s ~/.cache/thumbnails ~/.thumbnails

killall nautilus    # in case you are using nautilus
killall nemo        # in case you are using nemo
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I'm out of the woods, but a few things I noticed on my end.

### Debugging

There are no Nemo logs I could find, but someone else suggested enable warning messages by running `G_DEBUG=fatal_warnings gdb nemo`. You can run this in the terminal, then in another window launch Nemo from the command line for a folder with problematic thumbnailing `nemo /path/to/folder`. This would show warnings from Nemo.

### My findings

- **xplayer errors** `(xplayer-video-thumbnailer:21934): GLib-CRITICAL **: 10:34:21.307: Failed to set scheduler settings: Operation not permitted` - At the recommendation from stack overflow, I had installed xplayer thumbnailer. This was unhelpful. I uninstall all the player stuff I had installed. `sudo apt remove xplayer-thumbnailer xplayer xplayer-plugins xplayer-plugins-extra libxplayer`
- **vidoe thumbnails** For video, ffmpeg was enough - `sudo apt install ffmpegthumbs ffmpegthumbnailer`. If using Linux mint, you may need `mint-meta-codecs`.
- **raw thumbnails errors** - `Unable to create loader for mime type image/x-nikon-nef: Unrecognized image file format` - I was getting a lot of these. I think this was my initial issue, but I didn't discover how to debug Nemo until later. The advice [in this comment](https://gist.github.com/h4cc/13450db3d4a7457f9b38#gistcomment-3162296) was the best I could find (also in summary below.
- **Hidden files?** - at some point, it seemed that hidden files were blocking thumbnail generation. Deleting those seemed to help, but not sure if that was real.
- **pixel warnings** - can be ignored, [according to this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43038294/im-getting-error-deprecated-pixel-format-used-make-sure-you-did-set-range-corr/43038480). `deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly`

### Summary

1. Remove xplayer if you have it installed (command above)
2. For video thumbnails, install ffmpeg thumbnailer (command above)
3. For raw files, update:
   Open up /usr/share/thumbnailers/gdk-pixbuf-thumbnailer.thumbnailer and edit it to read as follows:

   ```
   [Thumbnailer Entry]
   TryExec=/usr/bin/gdk-pixbuf-thumbnailer
   Exec=/usr/bin/gdk-pixbuf-thumbnailer -s %s %u %o
   MimeType=image/png;image/bmp;image/x-bmp;image/x-MS-bmp;image/gif;image/x-icon;image/x-ico;image/x-win-bitmap;image/vnd.microsoft.icon;application/ico;image/ico;image/icon;text/ico;application/x-navi-animation;image/jpeg;image/x-portable-anymap;image/x-portable-bitmap;image/x-portable-graymap;image/x-portable-pixmap;image/tiff;image/x-xpixmap;image/x-xbitmap;image/x-tga;image/x-icns;image/x-quicktime;image/qtif;image/x-3fr;image/x-adobe-dng;image/x-arw;image/x-bay;image/x-canon-cr2;image/x-canon-crw;image/x-cap;image/x-cr2;image/x-crw;image/x-dcr;image/x-dcraw;image/x-dcs;image/x-dng;image/x-drf;image/x-eip;image/x-erf;image/x-fff;image/x-fuji-raf;image/x-iiq;image/x-k25;image/x-kdc;image/x-mef;image/x-minolta-mrw;image/x-mos;image/x-mrw;image/x-nef;image/x-nikon-nef;image/x-nrw;image/x-olympus-orf;image/x-orf;image/x-panasonic-raw;image/x-panasonic-raw2;image/x-pef;image/x-pentax-pef;image/x-ptx;image/x-pxn;image/x-r3d;image/x-raf;image/x-raw;image/x-rw2;image/x-rwl;image/x-rwz;image/x-samsung-srw;image/x-sigma-x3f;image/x-sony-arw;image/x-sony-sr2;image/x-sony-srf;image/x-sr2;image/x-srf;image/x-x3f;
   ```

   If you've a `raw.thumbnailer` or similar in that folder, delete it.
4. Clean up old thumbs:

   ```
   rm -Rf ~/.cache/thumbnails ~/.thumbnails
   killall nemo
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue myself, I fixed it by doing the following:

```
rm -Rf ~/.cache/thumbnails ~/.thumbnails
```

So what this does it deletes the thumbnail caches to get rid of any broken or miswritten thumbnails. The end result I found is that the xplayer used in Linux Mint got corrupted somehow on disk, my solution to fix that was to reinstall xplayer, and now my thumbnailing works again

```
sudo apt install --reinstall xplayer xplayer-plugins xplayer-plugins-extra libxplayer0
```

Comment: `~/.local/share/nemo` may contain the user's actions and scripts. I am pretty sure she does NOT want those deleted...

Comment: I will check, I have actually gotten this issue resolved on my own machine now, I will update the answer soon