# Nemo doesn't preview all thumbnails, and it's not size related

Tags: 16.04, cinnamon, nemo

Basically the same question as here: [Why doesn't Nemo preview thumbnails?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/395911/why-doesnt-nemo-preview-thumbnails)

However, I've tried all of those solutions and still have this issue.
Here's what I'm seeing:
[image: bad thumbnails]

As you can see, i'm getting previews of images which are larger in size than the ones i'm not getting previews for.  By the way, here's my settings for the size:
[image]

I've also tried the re-linking of the ~/.thumbnails to ~.cache/thumbnails:

```
~$ ls -la | grep thumbnails
```

lrwxrwxrwx  1 josh 1000      17 Mar 30 09:46 .thumbnails -> .cache/thumbnails

My system info:

```
Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS
Cinnamon 3.6.7
Nemo 3.6.5
```

Maybe it's fixed in an update of one of those?

Answer (score 0):

I am using nemo on Ubuntu 18.04. I also had the problem of no previews. After lots of searching for solutions and trying various settings with dconf-editor, I finally searched my computer for a thumbnails folder or file, found this:

```
~/.cache/thumbnails
```

Renamed it in case I needed to get it back:

```
mv ~/.cache/thumbnails ~/.cache/thumbnails~
```

and rebooted.

Nemo now shows the previews in icon view (the .cache now has a new thumbnails folder) and I deleted the renamed one:

```
rm -rf ~/.cache/thumbnails~
```

I hope this helps you as well.