# nemo-desktop taking too much RAM

Tags: 22.04, ram, nemo

On Ubuntu 22.04 I am using nemo-*. It's nice to use, but it has 2 core memory leaks.

1. Nemo - the file manager - here I usually am able to just close all the folder windows which kills the process and then open the folders again from scratch.
2. `nemo-desktop` - this is something I found answers mainly for CPU usage elswhere or some thumbnail clearance - for example here they are recommendations how to reduce the thumbail overload: https://askubuntu.com/a/575024/277898

I am "sharing the knowledge" here for the point 2. See my answer.

Comment: Please check https://github.com/linuxmint/nemo/issues/3306

Comment: @AhmadIsmail what about it?

Answer (score 2):

I originally thought `nemo-desktop` is for the whole GUI, **it is not.**

It's literally just that - a "desktop" app = it means it displays the icons on the desktop, nothing more. Not even the taskbar neither windows are tied to it...

**This means it can be shutdown and restarted with no issues**  Resulting in reseting the RAM usage.

### A. TL;DR Don't use the Desktop icons on the Desktop?

You can just `nemo-desktop --quit`.

Don't worry, Nemo file manager and "display desktop" (Super+D) will still work the same ;-)

### B. You need the Desktop icons

1. Open the terminal
2. `nemo-desktop --quit` - should end with "Killing nemo-desktop, as requested"
3. wait a few seconds for it to kill the `nemo-desktop` process (the quit seems to be asynchronous)
4. `nemo-desktop > /dev/null 2>&1 & disown nemo-desktop` (explanation below)
5. That's ALL => you **can** now **close** the terminal (see explanation below)

#### Explanation of `nemo-desktop > /dev/null 2>&1 & disown nemo-desktop`

- `nemo-desktop` is rerunning the `nemo-desktop`
- `2>&1` is redirecting standard ***error(2)*** to the standard ***output(1)***

  - the `&` **here** means it's a special file for standard output and ***not*** just some text file called "1" ([more info](https://superuser.com/a/71429/303640))
- `> /dev/null` is redirecting standard output to the oblivion (to null/nowhere)
- `&` **in the middle** means run the command in the background - allows to run other commands while this is running
- the other command `disown` unattaches the jobs/command runs from the current terminal - **this allows us to close the terminal safely (5.)** without the process we ran being killed
- `disown` ***doesn't need the job name***, but it can be provided as I did (`disown nemo-desktop`) to be more explicit and allow closing other attached jobs that you want to be closed when the terminal closes - but yes, to keep everything running it would just be `disown` and you can use it independetly anytime before you close the terminal to keep everything running what you've ran.

Note - **there is no <del>sudo</del>** - `nemo-desktop` is being run by normal user on purpose.

I am still not sure what is the root cause of the memory leak over time - since it's definitely not about thumbnails - I have cleared the thumbnail cache, set its settings to low size only and generally don't have that many thumbnail-related files. If this cause is resolved/found fix for any time in the future - feel free to comment or edit.